# No package.xml found: I am trying to deploy applications, classes, components, objects, pages etc from one sandbox to another

Tags: deployment, ant, migration, ant-script

I am unable to deploy the retrieved customizations from Sandbox. Please help.

Source: Developer Pro Sandbox
Destination: Developer Sandbox (dev sandbox is only for trial purpose, I need to deploy total application in partial copy sandbox)

Build.xml block:

```
 <target name="deploy">
<sf:deploy
  username="${sf.username}"
  password="${sf.password}"
  serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
  deployRoot="DST"
  rollbackOnError="True"/>
</target>
```

Error:

> DEPLOYMENT FAILED Request ID: 0Afc000000UyJuNCAV
>
> All Component Failures:
>   1.  package.xml -- Error: No package.xml found
>
> DEPLOYMENT FAILED

Comment: Your folder DST needs to have a package.xml in it. Ordinarily, if you used `sf:retrieve`, it should already be there.

Comment: @sfdcfox why should I need package.xml in root folder? Can you explain please. And Yes I used package.xml but I moved it to different folder as I am not referring any package.xml in sf:deploy target.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have package.xml in your root directory from where you are deploying the metadata. Looks like you have a folder named DST. Make sure you have create a package.xml file .

Package.xml can be generated using an IDE or by adding all components to an unmanaged package and then retrieving it from the package using ant retrieve.

Comment: how to create package.xml to deploy what I have in DST folder? I created package.xml manually to retrieve customizations. But now the deployment failed because of dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

When you use sf:retrieve, the folder you retrieve to will have a package.xml in it that already contains all of the elements you retrieved. This makes it easy to re-deploy the package to a new org using sf:deploy. Note that dependencies are not automatically resolved. I personally recommend creating a new package in Setup > Create > Packages, and then retrieving it with a package.xml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>demo</members>
        <name>Package</name>
    </types>
    <version>40.0</version>
</Package>
```

Once you retrieve it, you'll end up with the correctly built package.xml in the retrieved folder's root. Even better, building a package this way automatically includes all dependencies, so the package should deploy to a new environment seamlessly.

Comment: Thank you. This is very effective approach, I tried it but I got nothing. And I dont have test classes right now, and to upload package I will require test classes. Is there any way to avoid it.

Comment: @Alan You do not need unit tests to deploy to a sandbox or developer edition org.

Comment: Yeah I tried to upload that package but its asking test classes. And I am trying to deploy an application: both are completely different orgs, right now I have application in DevPro sandbox of unlimited edition org and I want to deploy it into enterprise edition sandbox(it can be dev sandbox or partial copy sandbox)

Comment: Can you tell me exact better approach for it. I am trying to do it with ANT. I am also trying to build package.xml as you told earlier.

Comment: @Alan If it's asking for unit tests, then you're deploying to a production org. You can use Ant, Force.com IDE, Workbench, MavensMate, or whatever. You just need to be deploying to the correct org, and not be missing any dependencies.